# Is there a quiet area to do some work on a laptop on a table before passing the security at SFO airport?

Tags: usa, air-travel, work, sfo, san-francisco-bay-area

I wonder whether there is any quiet area to do some work on a laptop on a table before passing the security at SFO airport. I know that after the security, there are some tables that one can use to work on a laptop, but I don't know about before passing the security.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are quiet areas in airports, except for maybe some lounges during low occupancy hours.

At the SFO airport there are some tables and seating area at the food court of the international departure hall that is before security. I don't think there's much in terms of seating space or quiet in the domestic terminals before you go through security.

Comment: "I don't think there are quiet areas in airports": sometimes there is, e.g. SLC airport top floor above the departure area. It has a few relatively quiet tables.